# Автоматическая очистка полей

Tags: php, html

Как убрать автоматическую очистку полей в php?
Т.е когда пользователь заполняет поля, и нажимает на кнопку, то поля очищаются.
Как это предотвратить?

Comment: не "поля очищаются", а страница перегружается

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать AJAX запрос при нажатии кнопки. Кнопка должна быть обычной кнопкой а не `<input type="submit">`. Это всё делается с помощью Javascript, PHP не понадобится.